# Oracle '+' operator with case statements?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I was looking at some oracle code and found these case statements are joined with a + operator? what does it do here? Is it possible to avoid '+' and do the same thing?

```
         case
           when t1.id is not null
             then 1
           else
             0
         end +
         case
           when t2.id is not null
             then 2
           else
             0
         end +
         case
           when t3.id is not null
             then 4
           else
             0
         end filter,
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious way to shorten the logic.

Comment: What is the + operator doing here? i'm not familiar with them.

Comment: just an ordinary addition

Comment: ahh i see! Thanks!

Comment: This creates a bit field on which ids are not null

Comment: perhaps you might shorten by using `nvl2(t1.id,1,0)+nvl2(t2.id,2,0)+nvl2(t3.id,4,0)`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Post that an answer.  Didn't know about `NVL2` +1.

Comment: Each `case` expression returns a number: the first one returns 0 or 1, the second one returns 0 or 2, etc. The "plus" sign is arithmetic addition of these values, and it has absolutely nothing to do with `case` - the plus sign only sees the results returned by evaluating those expressions, and those results are all integers.

Answer (score 4):

While your case represents an ordinary aritmetical operation of addition, an alternative way is to use [`NVL2()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions106.htm) function, which combines **null** and **non-null** cases as conditionals, to make it shorter such as

```
SELECT NVL2(t1.id,1,0)+NVL2(t2.id,2,0)+NVL2(t3.id,4,0) AS filter...
```

Answer (score 3):

Or, yet another option, `DECODE`:

```
select
  decode(t1.id, null, 0, 1) +
  decode(t2.id, null, 0, 2) +
  decode(t3.id, null, 0, 4) as filter
from ...
```

Comment: Cool to know that `DECODE` can do `NULL` equality checks +1.

Comment: Yes, @Tim, it can. However, the opposite won't work, e.g. `decode(t1.id, NOT NULL, 0, 1)` would return "ORA-00936: missing expression" error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any obvious way of making the logic more terse, but here is an explanation.

```sql
case when t1.id is not null then 1 else 0 end +   -- returns 1 or 0
case when t2.id is not null then 2 else 0 end +   -- returns 2 or 0
case when t3.id is not null then 4 else 0 end     -- returns 4 or 0
```

Each `CASE` expression above returns an integer value, either 1, 2, or 4 should the particular `id` be not `NULL`, or zero otherwise.  The `+` operator is simply summing these integer expressions together.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to avoid '+' and do the same thing?

In fact, yes.  Assuming the `id`s all have the same type, you can use a `lateral join`:

```
from . . . -- all your existing stuff here
     cross join lateral
     (select count(id) as cnt
      from (select t1.id from dual union all
                   t2.id from dual union all
                   t3.id from dual
           ) x
     ) x
```